# Concurrent IO Processing JAVA EE: Best Method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, glassfish, ejb, jms

I have an JavaEE 6 / EJB3.1 / Glassfish 3.1.2 application that retrieves .xml pages from a remote computer, converts them to java objects, then persists each of them in my mysql database. There are tens of thousands of these .xml pages and I'm just adding them incrementally. 
This is working great, except that it is very slow (70ms page retrieval + a tiny amount of time to convert & persist the entities).

I want to carry out this work concurrently to speed it up - what is the best method?

Possibly worth noting: each page retrieval updates a count in the mysql database for an OAuth credential it is using to get the page, and if it is at the max, it doesn't continue (throws an exception). I'm not sure if / how much this will complicate matters - but if two threads see it is below max, then get the page before updating the count it could go over the max.

My research so far has narrowed it down to two possibilities (feel free to add others though):

1. **Message Driven Beans** - I imagine, though are probably wrong, that I would have a session bean sending url messages until the message queue is full (say 10 url's are added), then blocks until the queue is not full. Glassfish will create 10 instances of a message bean I create who each get one of the .xml from one of the urls, update the OAuth count, then send this .xml as a message to another queue with another message bean that converts & persists .xmls from this queue.
2. **Use the @Asynchronous** method and create my own thread safe queue's? This could be much simpler and more suited to what I am doing but I'm not sure exactly how I would implement it.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a remote server, do you know how well it's going to scale? If you hit it with 10 threads will your response time become 700ms or will it stay steady at 70ms?

Assuming that the remote server will scale I think you're spot on with the MDB idea. However, some of your thoughts about it are inaccurate. You would create the session bean that submits to the queue. Where we differ is that I think you would want load the queue as quickly as the work is available. You can set a queue size and tell it whether it want it to throw away oldest or newest if that size is met. I suspect you want to consume all messages, and you can do that as well. I run queues with 100's of thousands of messages in them. You're really just limited to the in memory size of the queue which you can manage by making your messages as tight as possible.

On the consumption side, you would restrict the MDB pool to be 10 beans or whatever, it just depends on what the remote server is capable of scaling to and what your server is capable of scaling too. Rather than using 2 queues (and this is just based on the problem you described) I would use just the one. Create an MDB that does everything you're doing now, i.e. Grabbing the xml and persisting it. Lastly, if you find that you need to scale, it's just a matter of creating a cluster and adding nodes. Each node will then have an MDB pool that it's working with.

With regards to the Asychronous, how are going to control pool size and all the other things MDB's give you? I'm not saying you couldn't but it seems you'd be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The remote server will be capable of scaling perfectly within the bounds that I can scale to.  I implemented this with just one queue holding the url's and a MessageDrivenBean carrying out all of the logic. However, I am getting: `java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` on the line `em.merge(entity)` in my MessageDrivenBean. This happens every 50s (the inno_db_lock_wait_timeout). Can I concurrently merge? Or does this need to be separate?

Comment: 50s for a merge? Is that normal?

Comment: No, it only takes a fraction of a second, I suppose there is a deadlock somewhere. I've got around it at the moment by using bean managed transactions. I've realised that the concurrency issues are relatively complicated and that my understanding of transactions isn't fantastic so I am going to a bit more reading/tinkering and then see if I can solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I have gone ahead and sorted it out now. It would give me some assurance if you could confirm that it is a valid way of achieving what I wanted. I have used a Singleton Bean with:  `@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` 
to carry out all the merge operations through (single method). Also, to get around the 1000 messages limit of the message producer I have used `UserTransaction.begin()` and `ut.commit()` every 1000 messages added. This is all (appearing to) work well.

Comment: Your singleton won't scale once you go to a cluster. Have you tried Requiring a new transaction on the MDB. Without your code it's hard to see what you have going on, but it does sound abnormal.

Comment: Yes I did, but although each MDB had its own transaction the actual merge operation is critical in my code, so there was still concurrency issues with the other thread seeing out of date values. I fundamentally have to go through a single critical section somewhere (read-update-merge), either explicitly or through a JavaEE construct. This critical section is very fast so I have achieved my speedup goal, it is going a bit over 50x faster, limited by my network resources.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with Preston. In addition, if you realize that you need to scale by adding more nodes, make sure that you configure your JMS queue in a way that it accepts multiple consumers. That is a typical setup for an "application-level" load balancer, where work is being dispatched to workers.